# Windows installation on SSD with low storage

Tags: windows, ssd

I have a hybrid HDD which has 16GB as SSD. I would like to install windows and I am confused how to install windows on my SSD with low storage.

How does SSD work if I install windows on main hard drive ? I have windows 8.1 in my laptop right now which is installed on main hard drive and I could not figure out how SSD works. Could anyone please explain about this.

Answer (score 5):

A hybrid SSD is basically a normal HDD with a built-in SSD serving as a persistent cache.  Only one drive will appear on your computer; the drive's firmware will automatically distribute data between the SSD and the HDD by tracking which sectors are most frequently accessed and putting the more heavily used data on the SSD section.

You don't have to reinstall windows, just use your computer normally and the drive will become faster as it learns which parts of it are accessed most frequently.

Comment: is it the same case if I have dual boot system ... Does it work for both OS ?

Comment: yes, the hard drives firmware looks at the blocks read, not the file system or OS.]